# How to get a part of JSON string in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I have data something like this coming from a field ->

{"AddressLine1":"Example Dr","AddressLine2":"","City":"Paradise City","State":"State Name","PostalCode":"12345","Zip5":"67891","Zip4":""}

{"AddressLine1":"Ex Ln","AddressLine2":"Adr 22","City":"","State":"State Name","PostalCode":"12345","Zip5":"67891","Zip4":""}

I need to extract the value in quotes beside "City":. In above cases I need  values - **Paradise City** and **NULL**.

Comment: This looks almost like JSON; any reason you cannot receive this data in proper JSON format? Oracle has excellent support for JSON - then you wan't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: We get this data from another source system. We need to deal with this data as is and extrat values from them

Comment: Your JSON is invalid as the double quote is missing from before `AddressLIne1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       jt.*
FROM   table_name t
       OUTER APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$'
         ERROR ON ERROR
         COLUMNS (
           AddressLine1 VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.AddressLine1',
           AddressLine2 VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.AddressLine2',
           City         VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.City',
           State        VARCHAR2(200) PATH '$.State',
           PostalCode   VARCHAR2(7)   PATH '$.PostalCode',
           Zip5         VARCHAR2(5)   PATH '$.Zip5',
           Zip4         VARCHAR2(4)   PATH '$.Zip4'
         )
       ) jt;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id INT, value CLOB CHECK ( value IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( id, value )
SELECT 1, '{"AddressLine1":"Example Dr","AddressLine2":"","City":"Paradise City","State":"State Name","PostalCode":"12345","Zip5":"67891","Zip4":""}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '{"AddressLine1":"Ex Ln","AddressLine2":"Adr 22","City":"","State":"State Name","PostalCode":"12345","Zip5":"67891","Zip4":""}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | ADDRESSLINE1 | ADDRESSLINE2 | CITY          | STATE      | POSTALCODE | ZIP5  | ZIP4
> -: | :----------- | :----------- | :------------ | :--------- | :--------- | :---- | :---
>  1 | Example Dr   | null         | Paradise City | State Name | 12345      | 67891 | null
>  2 | Ex Ln        | Adr 22       | null          | State Name | 12345      | 67891 | null
>  3 | null         | null         | null          | null       | null       | null  | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a2c767c1c50bd219d7f075fab572991e)*

Comment: Is there a way to improve this query so that I can get other columns too from main table even when there are nulls in the json string field?

Comment: @Shru Yes, just add them to the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: That is exactly what i did but what I noticed is the query is filtering out all the rows that have null value in the field that is carrying json string. My requirement is to bring all the rows from main table irrespective of json string presence.

Comment: @Shru Ah, misunderstood what you were asking. Change `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY`.